# Изменение свойств блока (высота, смещение) по событию scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3

есть блок который по мере прокрутки меняет свою высоту, все работает нормально, но решил усложнить задачу. 
Скомбинировать, чтобы по мере прокрутки страницы менялась не только высота но и смещение блока от левого края. все почти работает только по очереди.

то есть когда в коде присутствует эта строка

```
block.css('height', height) = height + 'px';
```

то работает она.

А если эта
    `block.css('left', left) = left + 'px';` - то она.

но если включены обе, то срабатывает только первая.

вот сам код, не ругайтесь на на грязь (знаю что можно сократить, сегодня первый день изучаю scroll, мне бы пока просто работоспособности добиться).
https://jsfiddle.net/engenes/apug62bu/5/

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .block{
    height:200px;
        width: 100%;
        position:fixed;
        top: 25px;
        background:#333;
        transition: 200ms;
    }
    body{
        height: 10000px;
    }
    .block.active{
        background:red;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div claSS ="bl">
        <div claSS ="block">
        </div>
    </div>
        <script>
        var wnd = $(window),
            block = $('.block');

        wnd.scroll(function(){
            var top = wnd.scrollTop(),
                height = 200;
                if(height < top){
                height=top / 15*2;
                left=15;
                $('.block').addClass("active");
                }
                if(top > 2800){
                $('.block').addClass("active");
                height=500;
                left= ((-200 + top) / 20);
                }
                else if(top < 2800){
                $('.block').removeClass("active");
                }   
           block.css('height', height) = height + 'px';
           block.css('left', left) = left + 'px';

    });
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
block.css('height', height) = height + 'px';
на эту строку ругается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в неправильном использовании функции `css`.

Для установки значения достаточно

```
block.css('height', height)
```

<strike>далее вы переопределяете сам объект block - поэтому вторая строка и не работала.</strike>
Как правильно заметил [user198223](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/479166/186999) - вы пытаетесь присвоить что-то результату функции и происходит ошибка и все падает.

Для решения, вариант из соседнего ответа, либо просто убрать присвоения:

```
block.css('height', height);
block.css('left', left);
```

Comment: решил еще усложнить, а если нужно чтобы при скроле у соседнего блока при появлении его в поле видимости (100px от низу) он тоже начал смещаться относительно левого края. Подскажите, если можно) вот заготовку изменил: https://jsfiddle.net/engenes/apug62bu/17/

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, честно говоря так накрутили, что не понял что именно хотите :-) но никто не мешает так же взять этот элемент и в зависимости от положения скрола поменять ему координаты

Comment: нет нет, Это первое что я подумал. но допустим это страничка в которую перед нужным нам элементом помещен какой то контент, размер которого меняется, и соответственно положение этого блока будет сползать то выше то ниже. А условие должно оставаться неизменным, (его горизонтальные координаты должны начать меняться, как только он появится в поле видимости больше чем на 100px от низу) вот почистил от лишнего, не стал трогать скрипт только:https://jsfiddle.net/engenes/apug62bu/21/

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, в текущем примере у блока стоит position:absolute - а следовательно ему все равно на другие элементы, его координаты постоянны относительно родителя, в любом случае в момент скролла получаются реальные координаты элемента и всегда можно проверить входит ли он в определенный интервал или нет

Comment: наверное я не так понял, или не так написал... Если будет position:relarive; А и я напишу: измени цвет, когда я прокручу страницу на 500px. Блок то цвет изменит, но я могу этого не увидеть если перед ним контента будет пикселей на 800 по высоте. А для меня весь интерес в том и заключается, что хочу, чтобы все эффекты были видны) то есть в момент появления блока в поле видимости на определенной высоте. Я просто решил все в одной тебе чтобы использовать в качестве закладки для себя.))

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, не, во-первых, всегда можно узнать текущую координату элемента, реальную, во-вторых, без конкретного пример все равно тяжело понять, и в третьих по сути это другой вопрос, вроде: как узнать при прокрутке, что элемент попал в область видимости. Который, мне кажется, лучше отдельно спросить с конкретным примером

Comment: завтра разложу все по полочкам. спрошу)

Answer (score 1):

```
block.css({'height': height, 'left': left});
```

Вот так попробуйте

Comment: спасибо) только непонятно откуда он знает что числовые значения это именно px а не % например?

Comment: По умолчанию в пикселях, можно записать еще `width('30%');` вроде бы) Не уверен на счет jQuery.